# mapPartitions Vs foreach plus accumulator approach

Tags: java, scala, foreach, apache-spark

There are some cases in which I can obtain the same results by using the mapPartitions or the foreach method.

For example in a typical MapReduce approach one would perform a reduceByKey immediately after a mapPartitions that transforms the original RDD in a collection of tuple (key, value). I think that it is possible to achieve the same result by using, for instance an array of accumulator where at each index an executor sums a value and the index itself could be a key.

Since the reduceByKey will perform a shuffle on disk, I think that when it is possible, the foreach approach should be better even though the foreach has the side effect of sum a value to an accumulator.

I am making this request to see if my reasoning is correct . I hope I was clear.

Comment: c) Nether of the above.  `aggregateByKey` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) is there for exactly this sort of use-case

Comment: @Paul: I don't see how `aggregateByKey` would be helpful here. It does the shuffle just like `reduceByKey`, except it's a bit more flexible and less convenient to use.

Comment: Sorry, correct. I was confusing it with reduceByKeyLocally

Answer (score 0):

Don't use aggregators for this. They are less reliable. (For example they can be double-counted if speculative execution is enabled.)

But the approach you describe has its merits.

- With `reduceByKey` there is a shuffle. The upside is that it can handle more keys than would fit on a single machine.
- With the `foreach` + aggregator method you avoid the shuffle. But now you cannot handle more keys than can fit on one machine. Also you have to know the keys in advance so that you can create the aggregators. The code becomes a mess too.

If you have a low number of keys, then the `reduceByKeyLocally` method is what you need. It's basically the same as your aggregator trick, except it doesn't use aggregators, you don't have to know the keys in advance, and it's a drop-in replacement for `reduceByKey`.

[`reduceByKeyLocally`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala#L292) creates a hashmap for each partition, sends the hashmaps to the driver and merges them there.

Comment: Could you please explain, more in detail, the difference between reduceByKeyLocally and reduceByKey? Thanks!!

Comment: I think I've already explained, plus there is the link to the source code if you want all the details. Do you have a specific question that's not answered by my answer? With `reduceByKey` you have a shuffle that sends each key to the right partition. With the aggregator trick and `reduceByKeyLocally` the keys are sent to the driver instead. But this is already in the answer. I'm not sure what you're looking for, sorry.

Comment: Sorry man, you're right. It was already clear.. Now I'm wondering why the accumulators are less reliable? (except the case of the speculative execution). Thank you very much!